# Reshape tensorflow tensors from feature columns into training samples

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently my dataset looks like:

```
feat_1 = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[8000,1],
    minval=0,
    maxval=1,
    dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,
    seed=1123,
    name=None
)

feat_2 = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[8000,24],
    minval=0,
    maxval=1,
    dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,
    seed=1123,
    name=None
)

feat_3 = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[8000,26],
    minval=0,
    maxval=1,
    dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,
    seed=1123,
    name=None
)

# Current_state
dataset = (feat_1, feat_2, feat_3)
```

How can I reshape it in tensorflow so that the dataset is instead shaped like:
(8000,3) where the 3 is a record from each of the three feat_3 tensors?

so rather than have:
((8000,), (8000,24), (8000,26))
I want an 8000 long tensor with each item looking like
((1,), (24,), (26,))

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with `where the 3 is a record from each of the three feat_3 tensors`

Comment: Just added some more detail on how I want it reshaped

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding how reshaping works. The way you put it means you've lost basically 99% of your data. Currently, for example feat_2 is 8000*24 data points, while you're intended output is 24 data points.

Comment: I believe what you want to do is `tf.concat(dataset, axis=1)`, which gives a tensor of shape (8000, 51)

Comment: @user2246849 can I have the (8000,3) with the 2nd and third columns being nested arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

feat_1 = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[8000,1],
    minval=0,
    maxval=1,
    dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,
    seed=1123,
    name=None
)

feat_2 = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[8000,24],
    minval=0,
    maxval=1,
    dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,
    seed=1123,
    name=None
)

feat_3 = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[8000,26],
    minval=0,
    maxval=1,
    dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,
    seed=1123,
    name=None
)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((feat_1, feat_2, feat_3))

for x, y, z in dataset.take(1):
  print(x.shape, y.shape, z.shape)

# (1,) (24,) (26,)
```

Otherwise, you could also consider using a ragged tensor or `tf.tuple` if you want a single tensor.